# Why is set.contains not using overriden equals() method?

Tags: java, set, equals, contains, hashset

I have a class like this:

```
class Vertex {
    char v;
    char w;
    int cost;

    public Vertex(char v, char w, int cost){
        this.v = v;
        this.w = w;
        this.cost = cost;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return "["+v+" "+w+" "+cost+"]";
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Vertex vertex = (Vertex) o;
        return (v == vertex.v && w == vertex.w) || (w == vertex.v && v == vertex.w);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(v, w);
    }
}
```

I am trying to have the `equals()` return true when two vertexes are equal or opposite equal. Meaning it should return true if there is a vertex (v,w) and (w,v).

My `equals()` is symmetric and reflexive as it should be, but still the `set.contains()` return false for (v,w) and (w,v) case.

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Have you tried debugging your code?

Comment: The `set.contains` of a `HashSet` is going to compare by `hashCode()` (first) and your vertices `v,w` and `w,v` have different hash codes.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch that makes sense, do you know how can I get them to have same hashcodes?

Comment: You could try `return v+w;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your class violates the general contract for `hashCode()`, not `equals()`. `Set.contains()` uses `hashCode()` to achieve O(1) time.

The general contract for `hashCode()` states that equal objects must have equal hash codes. However, in your case, `[v=1, w=2]` and `[v=2, w=1]` are considered equal, but they have different hash codes. You'd be calling `Objects.hash(1, 2)` and `Objects.hash(2, 1)` respectively.

You should change your hash code implementation to make it independent of the order of `v` and `w`. One way to do this is to hash the smaller one first:

```
return Objects.hash(Math.min(v, w), Math.max(v, w));
```

Answer (score 1):

As @Sweeper wrote, your hashCode should return same value in any parameters order, so you can return sum of parameters' hashCode:

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hashCode(v) + Objects.hashCode(w);
}
```